# Gorename not working: "Rename failed: gorename: can't find package containing"

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

When trying to change the symbols, VSCode throws the following error:

**"Rename failed: gorename: can't find package containing /home/hume/projects/go/main.go"**

> vscode 1.22.2 x64
>
> go version go1.10.1 linux/amd64
>
> go env GOPATH /home/hume/projects/go

My `settings.json` is as follows:

```
{
      "go.toolsGopath": "/home/hume/gotools"
    , "go.autocompleteUnimportedPackages": true
    , "go.inferGopath": true
    , "go.formatTool": "gofmt"
    , "go.vetFlags": [
        "/src"
       ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your `main.go` isn't in a package directory. Start here: [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: That's not the problem, I know how it's structured, it's just an simple example.

Comment: yes it is _a_ problem. The error contains the path which shows it's not a valid package path. I can reproduce the exact same error locally, and moving the file into a proper package directory fixes the issue.

Comment: you are right;), but it seems that the code should not have errors, but it does not work, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You can switch to using [gopls](https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/gopls), the official Go language server. Besides other featured renaming symbols works perfectly regardless of any package structure.

In VSC open Preferences, Settings, and activate `go.useLanguageServer`. After installing *gpls* you are ready to go.

Comment: Spent literally an hour on this, thank you! It seems gorename attempts to search my entire $GOPATH, failing on any packages that use gomod. This is definitely the best solution

Answer (score 0):

VSCode uses `gorename` command-line tool to do rename. The tool supposes you are following the right package structure but it fails to find it. Create a `src` directory in `%GOPATH%`, i.e. create directory `/home/hume/projects/go/src`. Create another directory in `src` as the package directory and put `main.go` in the package directory. You need to add package declaration at `main.go`. Then the problem is resoved.